# Using the output of one script in another scri

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a way to get certain results of the script (the weight, length, stab_damage, slash_damage) into another script without requiring the player to do all the inputs again. I have little experience with python and am trying to make a small game and need these so when the person is equipped with the shortsword, the weight, length and damages will stay with the player. If this is impossible to do, I will understand, and would not be surprised.

```
shortsword = weapon
user_input = float(raw_input("input number between 2-5 for blade length: "))
tip_input = float(raw_input("input number between 1-4 for blade point: "))
blade_input = float(raw_input("subtract blade length from 6, add 2: "))
length = user_input*8
weight = 500*length
from decimal import *
tipsharpness = 2 * tip_input
stab_damage = tipsharpness * 3
slash_damage = blade_input * user_input
from random import randint
attack = (randint(0, 9))
if attack < 5:
    print "Stab"
    print stab_damage
else:
    print "Slash"
    print slash_damage
print length "inchs"`
```

Comment: Refactor so you use functions and don't use stdout directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for calling another script with arguments:

```
import os
s_execute = "script.py %s %s" % (param_1, param_2)
os.system(s_execute)
```

And in your other script, get the parameters using [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

```
import sys  
param_1= sys.argv[1] 
param_2= sys.argv[2]  
print param_1, param_2
```

Comment: would the player have to reinput the weapon length and such with that?

Comment: No, the program pass the parameters with the values (user_input,tip_input and blade_input), the second script save the parameters as variables with the values that the user wrote in the first script.

Comment: alright. I will try and see if I can get this to work, one more quick question, do I need to rename the parameters in the code you have provided with the values (user_input, etc?)

Comment: Yes you can, but in the code your provided above, I used the parameters as the inputs of the user (user_input,tip_input and blade_input).